# getting exception System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I get this exception but cant seem to find my issue:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in System.Net.Http.dll
```

I am logging into a server with username and password, and the process is working just fine.

Heres my code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    teamScreen = "https://thewebsite.com/teambeta/Login.aspx?" + "username=" +
        logInUserIdString + "&password=" + logInPasswordString +
        "&mobile=1&offsetHours=" + timezone;
    webView1.Navigate(targetUri);
}
```

But I dont want to submit an app to the store with the issue not resolved.

Does anyone know what the issue is as I cant seem to track down why I am getting the exception?  Thanks.

Comment: can you check if your exception has an inner exception set?

Answer (score 0):

still not solved but I did fix the following as I did not have the Uri set correctly.

Here is the correct code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    teamScreen = "https://thewebsite.com/teambeta/Login.aspx?" + "username=" +
        logInUserIdString + "&password=" + logInPasswordString +
        "&mobile=1&offsetHours=" + timezone;
    Uri targetUri = new Uri(teamScreen);
    webView1.Navigate(targetUri);
}
```

not sure why it actually worked before as I never set the URI.  Very strange, but still getting the error.